# Proving a group is abelian and of odd order?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group

We were given the following question:

Let $\phi : G \rightarrow G$ be an automorphism of the finite group $G$ which fixes only the identity element. Show that every element of G can be written in the form $g^{-1}\phi(g)$. Moreover, show that if $\phi \circ \phi = id_{G}$, then G is an abelian group and the group is of odd order.

For the first part of the proof, here is my reasoning, though I do not know if it's correct, or how I can prove it. Since G is a group, and we define an automorphism, essentially it is a permutation of all the elements. So for any $g \in G$, we can find $\phi(g)$ which maps it to g. But this is not a formal proof. And my reasoning feels a little shaky.

For the second part,  if we can prove the first part, we have that $\forall$ $a,b \in G$, we have that $a \times b = a^{-1}\phi(a) \times b^{-1}\phi(b)$. But how can we leverage here the fact that $\phi \circ \phi = id_{G}$? We don't have $\phi \circ \phi$ anywhere in the equation unless I am understanding something incorrectly. So how can I show the group is abelian of odd order?

Comment: Your proof of the first part is not right. The fact that $\phi$ is an automorphism tells you nothing a priori about the function $\psi(g) = g^{-1} \phi(g)$. For example if $\phi(g) = g$ for all $g$ then $\psi(g) = 1$, so you'd better use in your argument somewhere the fact that $\phi$ has no fixed points apart from the identity. Hint: You want to show $\psi$ is surjective. Can you show that it is injective? (Note it is just a function, not a homomorphism in general.)

Comment: For the first part notice that you are saying that $g=g^{-1}\phi(g)$, which is not correct. What you have to prove is that for every $g\in G$ there is some $h\in G$ such that $g=h^{-1}\phi(h)$.

Comment: For the second part, given $x \in G$ we can write $x = g^{-1} \phi(g)$ by the first part. What does $\phi$ do this?